# Is EOF hidden in txt file?

Tags: eof

I have made an .exe file (echo_eof.exe) which is written in C.
The code goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) 
{
    int ch;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(ch);

}
```

Then I typed **echo_eof < words.txt** in Windows cmd where words.txt is written as

```
Hello world!
```

The command output is

```
Hello world!
```

I have never typed EOF in the text file but it seems like EOF is hidden in the text file. Is this true? If it is, is there a way to see the hidden EOF in the text file?

Comment: no it's an OS value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your reading function is at the end of the file and can't get another symbol (probably char), then it gets told that you have reached EOF. 
This is not in the file, it is a signal from the filehandler.